# CAGradientLayer does not display

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton, cagradientlayer

I have looked over a bunch of other answers to questions like this, but none of the answers seem to solve my problem, so looking for a little help.

I'm trying to apply a vertical gradient to a UIButton, but the gradient layer is just not showing up in my view.  Here is the relevant code:

```
let darkPurple = UIColor(displayP3Red: 61.0/255.0, green: 3.0/255.0, blue: 110.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
let lightPurple = UIColor(displayP3Red: 90.0/255.0, green: 32.0/255.0, blue: 130.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

let addButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))
addButton.title = "Start counting"
addButton.layer.cornerRadius = 30.0
addButton.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
addButton.layer.borderColor = darkPurple.cgColor
addButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
myView.addSubview(addButton)
addButton.applyGradient(with: [lightPurple, darkPurple], gradientOrientation: .vertical)
```

...and the code to apply the gradient:

```
typealias GradientPoints = (startPoint: CGPoint, endPoint: CGPoint)

enum GradientOrientation {
  case topRightBottomLeft
  case topLeftBottomRight
  case horizontal
  case vertical

  var startPoint: CGPoint {
    return points.startPoint
  }

  var endPoint: CGPoint {
    return points.endPoint
  }

  var points: GradientPoints {
    switch self {
    case .topRightBottomLeft:
      return (CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0), CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.0))
    case .topLeftBottomRight:
      return (CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0), CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0))
    case .horizontal:
      return (CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0), CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.0))
    case .vertical:
      return (CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0), CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0))
    }
  }
}

extension UIView {
  func applyGradient(with colors: [UIColor], gradientOrientation orientation: GradientOrientation) {
    let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.frame = self.bounds
    gradient.colors = colors.map { $0.cgColor }
    gradient.startPoint = orientation.startPoint
    gradient.endPoint = orientation.endPoint
    gradient.borderColor = self.layer.borderColor
    gradient.borderWidth = self.layer.borderWidth
    gradient.cornerRadius = self.layer.cornerRadius
    gradient.masksToBounds = true
    gradient.isHidden = false

    self.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
  }
}
```

This is what I get:
[empty button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPiqN.png)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Auto Layout doesn't affect the layers of `UIView` objects, so the gradient layer is being applied too early, before the frame of the `UIButton` has been calculated.  When the `frame` property of the gradient layer is assigned, the bounds of the button are still equal to `CGRect.zero`, and the gradient layer frame is never updated later.

You'll find that if you add your gradient layer **after** the button frame has been calculated, it works as expected.  For example:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    let darkPurple = UIColor(displayP3Red: 61.0/255.0, green: 3.0/255.0, blue: 110.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    let lightPurple = UIColor(displayP3Red: 90.0/255.0, green: 32.0/255.0, blue: 130.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

    addButton.applyGradient(with: [lightPurple, darkPurple], gradientOrientation: .vertical)
}
```

[image]

Another option would be to update the `frame` property of the gradient layer in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` or create a custom `UIButton` subclass and update the gradient layer frame whenever the frame of the button updates.

[Reference](https://medium.com/@marcosantadev/calayer-and-auto-layout-with-swift-21b2d2b8b9d1)

Answer (score 20):

For anyone who already spent hours of searching (like I did):

Make sure, that your colors array contains `CGColor` instead of `UIColor`, as per docs:

> **colors**
>
> An array of CGColorRef objects defining the color of each
> gradient stop. Animatable.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cagradientlayer/1462403-colors

Bonus: this little code snippet will crash app, if you miss it again (using `#if DEBUG` is recommended)

```
extension CAGradientLayer {
    dynamic var colors: [Any]? {
        get { self.value(forKey: "colors") as? [Any] }
        set {
            if let newValue = newValue {
                for color in newValue {
                    if color is UIColor {
                        fatalError("CAGradientLayer.colors must contain only CGColor! UIColor was found")
                    }
                }
            }
            super.setValue(newValue, forKey: "colors")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how did I miss that!

Comment: @Prajwal not ours fault, `colors` has type `[Any]`, blame Apple devs)

Comment: @DmytroRostopira Thank you so much. I don't know how, I missed it.

Answer (score 0):

Sublayers are in back-to-front order. Inserting a layer at index 0 will place it behind any other sublayers. I've never tried to do that with a button, but suspect it has at least 1 sublayer that is covering the gradient you are trying to add.

Try using `addSublayer()` instead, which will put the layer on the top of the sublayers array.

### Edit:

I built a variant of your code and when I change `self.layer.insertSublayer(_:at:)` to `addSublayer()`, it works.

Comment: You're right about this, for sure.  In my case, I needed to make sure the gradient shows up behind the button title, so `self.layer.insertSublayer(_:at:)` won't work for me.  I did, however, have this backward, thinking that 0 would be the top.  Thanks for the correction!